# Custom validator parameter doesn't react to changes

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I got a custom validator that expects a string parameter. However when i change the parameter in code that doesn't change an initial value that was passed during form initialization. The only workaround I found is to remove validator and add it again with new parameter.

Is it a desired behaviour? How can i force angular to "reload" validator parameter?

[Demo of unwanted behaviour.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ndwgtu)

Code:

**HTML**

```
<form [formGroup]="reactiveForm">
    <input type="text" formControlName="input">
  <button (click)="changeToB()" >switch to b</button>
<br>
  valid: {{reactiveForm.get('input').valid}}
  <br>
  shouldBeEqualTo: {{shouldBeEqualTo}}
</form>
```

**TS**

```
export class AppComponent {
  shouldBeEqualTo = 'a';
  reactiveForm: FormGroup;
  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.reactiveForm = this.fb.group({input: ['a', customValidator(this.shouldBeEqualTo)]})
  }

  changeToB(){
    this.shouldBeEqualTo = 'b';
  }
}

export function customValidator(equalTo: string): ValidatorFn{
 return (c: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: any } => {
   console.log(equalTo)
   console.log(c.value)
   if(c.value !== equalTo){
     return {valid: false};
   }
   return null;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You may need to add custome validator to form instead of the form control this way you can have access to local property.

*component*

```
  shouldBeEqualTo = 'a';
  reactiveForm: FormGroup;
  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.reactiveForm = this.fb.group({ input: ['a' ]},
                      {validator:this.getCustomeValidator()})
  }

  changeToB() {
    this.shouldBeEqualTo = 'b';
  }

  getCustomeValidator() {
    return (c: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: any } => {
      if (c.value !== this.shouldBeEqualTo) {
        return { valid: false };
      }
      return null;
    }
  }
}
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uo8coz)

Another way may consider can make the validator reusable,but I still recommand first solution

```
export class AppComponent {
  shouldBeEqualTo = 'a';
  reactiveForm: FormGroup;
  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.reactiveForm = this.fb.group({input: ['a', customValidator(this,'shouldBeEqualTo')]})
  }

  changeToB(){
    this.shouldBeEqualTo = 'b';
  }
}

export function customValidator($this,property:string): ValidatorFn{
 return (c: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: any } => {
   if(c.value !== $this[property]){
     return {valid: false};
   }
   return null;
 }
}
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-eoyfa8)

Comment: This way i lost a validator reusability in other forms. It also feels hacky doesn't it?

Comment: Your validator depend on other value that may going to update like class property if 's will not be possible in that case you make the validator not reusable :\

Comment: it is working. However i'd wait to mark question as answered. Maybe i will figure out how to extract validator to make it reusable across components. Thank you anyway.

Comment: I have add another solution @karoluS